# Error al crear procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando un procedimiento en mysql, pero al ejecutar la consulta me arroja el siguiente error: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 23.

La linea 23 es la siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO asegurados (claveafilido, rfc, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, telefono, fechainiciovigencia, fechafinvigencia, codigoProducto) VALUES ( varClaveAfiliado, varRfc, varNombre, varApellidoP, varApellidoM, varTelefono, varFechaInicioVigencia, varFechaFinVigencia, varCodigoProducto);
```

Este el código completo del procedimiento:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE OperacionEntradaAsegurados (
varId int,
varNombre varchar(100),
varApellidoP varchar(100),
varApellidoM varchar(100),
varNacimiento varchar(100),
varGenero varchar(100),
varEstadoCivil varchar(100),
varOcupacion varchar(100),
varPaisNacimiento varchar(100),
varNacionalidad varchar(100),
varCurp varchar(100),
varRfc varchar(100),
varCodigoProducto varchar(100),
varClaveAfiliado varchar(5),
varTelefono varchar(10),
varFechaInicioVigencia date,
varFechaFinVigencia date
)

BEGIN
    IF (varId=0) THEN
        INSERT INTO asegurados (claveafilido, rfc, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, telefono, fechainiciovigencia, fechafinvigencia, codigoProducto) VALUES ( varClaveAfiliado, varRfc, varNombre, varApellidoP, varApellidoM, varTelefono, varFechaInicioVigencia, varFechaFinVigencia, varCodigoProducto);

        SELECT @@IDENTIFY AS 'Identify';

      ELSE
        UPDATE asegurados
            SET   claveafilido=varClaveAfiliado,  rfc=varRfc, nombre=varNombre, apellidoPaterno=varApellidoP, apellidoMaterno=varApellidoM, telefono=varTelefono, fechainiciovigencia=varFechaInicioVigencia, fechafinvigencia=varFechaFinVigencia  WHERE id=varId;
      END IF;
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el error en los ' ' al insertar los datos a la tabla